# Prove a cyclic subgroup is normal?

Tags: group-theory

I've got a question that asks me to find a cyclic subgroup of $D_{12}$ of order 6.  $D_{12} = <r, s | r^{12} = s^2 = e, sr = r^{11}s>$

My answer to this is :

{$e, r^2, r^4, r^6, r^8, r^{10}$} or {$e, r^2s, r^4, r^6s, r^8, r^{10}s$}.

The question I have for you is that I'm then asked to prove that whichever subgroup I choose is a normal subgroup.  I would normally say that it is a normal subgroup, because it is cyclic and therefore Abelian and normal too.  Also, it must be a subgroup of $D_{12}$ because it is generated by an element of $D_{12}$.  However, it is a 4 mark question, so am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: You incorrectly computed $(r^2 s)^2$

Comment: If $D_{12}$ were abelian, then every subgroup would be normal. The fact that the subgroup is abelian is not helpful

Comment: An abelian subgroup is not necessarily normal. A subgroup being abelian is about what happens when you multiply elements within that group with one another, a subgroup being normal is about what happens when you multiply elements inside the subgroup with elements outside the subgroup. The two concepts have little influence on one another.

Comment: $S = \{e, s\}$ is a subgroup of $D_{12}$ and $S$ is abelian, but $S$ is not a normal subgroup of $D_{12}$

Comment: Yeah, actually I don't know why I said that, it's not really relevant.

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note  that the subgroup $\langle r \rangle = \{e, r, r^2, \ldots, r^{11}\}$ has index $2$ in $D_{12}$ and is therefore normal in $D_{12}$. Moreover, $\langle r \rangle$ is cyclic, so it contains exactly one subgroup of each possible order. This means that every subgroup of $\langle r \rangle$ is **characteristic** in $\langle r \rangle$.

There is a useful general theorem which is easy to prove: if $H \lhd G$ and $K$ is a characteristic subgroup of $H$, then $K \lhd G$. Applying this result with $K = \langle r^2 \rangle = \{e, r^2, r^4, \ldots, r^{10}\}$ and $H = \langle r \rangle$ and $G = D_{12}$, we can conclude immediately that $K \lhd G$.

In fact, by the same reasoning, every subgroup of $\langle r\rangle$ is normal in $G$.

---

For completeness, here is a proof of the theorem used above. Suppose that $H \lhd G$ and $K$ is characteristic in $H$. The latter means exactly that any automorphism of $H$ fixes $K$, in other words if $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ then $\phi(K) = K$. Let $g$ be any element in $G$, and let $\phi_g$ denote conjugation by $g$. Then $\phi_g$ is an automorphism on $G$. Moreover, since $H \lhd G$, we see that $\phi_g$ fixes $H$ (i.e. $\phi_g(H) = H$), so $\phi_g|_H$ (the restriction of $\phi_g$ to $H$) is an automorphism of $H$ and therefore fixes $K$. In other words, $\phi_g(K) = K$. But $\phi_g(K) = gKg^{-1}$, so by definition this means that $K \lhd G$.

Comment: So, the characteristic subgroups for <$r$> would be <$r^2$>, <$r^3$>, <$r^4$> and <$r^6$>?  I haven't come across the concept of characteristic subgroups before, sounds very useful.

Comment: @MikeA Those, along with $\langle r \rangle$ itself and also the trivial subgroup $\{e\}$, are all of the subgroups of $\langle r\rangle$, and they are all characteristic subgroups of $\langle r \rangle$ because $\langle r\rangle $ is cyclic (and finite). You will probably encounter the notion of characteristic before long as you continue studying group theory. You can think of it as a stronger form of normality. Normal groups are fixed by **inner** automorphisms (conjugation by any element), whereas characteristic subgroups are fixed by **all** automorphisms.

Comment: @MikeA A good rule of thumb is that if a subgroup is unique in some sense (e.g. if it is the only subgroup of a given order), then it is characteristic.

Comment: That's really interesting, it makes for a really succinct proof as well.  Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing $r,s$ generates $G$, we only need to check $rHr^{-1}=sHs^{-1}=H$ to show a subgroup $H$ is normal in $G$.

This is clear for your subgroups. But the second subgroup seems not cyclic.

Comment: Why is the second subgroup not cyclic?  I must have made a mistake.

Comment: @MikeA There is no element of order 6:$r^2sr^2s=r^2r^{22}ss=1$, etc.

Comment: Is there a correct version of my second subgroup or is it completely wrong?

Comment: @MikeA There are only two element of order 6 in $G$, namely, $r^2, r^{10}$. So there is only one cyclic subgroup of order 6 in $G$.

Comment: I was on the wrong track entirely with that one then.  Thanks for clearing that one up!

Answer (score 1):

i believe that a theorem along the lines "let $p$ be the smallest prime dividing the order of the group $G$.  If $H\leq G$ is a subgroup of index $p$, then $H$ is normal in $G$" will help you find the answer

Comment: So, in this case the smallest prime is 2, but my subgroup order is 6?  I may be misunderstanding.

Comment: @MikeA ah, my mistake! Should be "of index", i corrected my comment. Recall the definition of index for finite groups

Comment: So the index is the order of G divided by the order of H IIRC, so the index in this case is $24/6=4$.  Doesn't p=2 in this case?

Comment: Didn't realize the question specified order 6, I was hinting at finding a subgroup of order 12, my mistake

Comment: My comment would have been more appropriate for the subgroup $< r >$

Comment: Ahh ok, I was scratching my head on that one.  To be honest, group theory in general I find hard to grasp, which is think is pretty evident from my comments.

Comment: @MikeA it's a very tricky subject, but you're clearly engaging in conversation instead of just searching for the answers, so good for you! Learning why methods (such as the one I proposed) don't work is arguably just as important as learning the methods that do work

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that!